# Preferred address not being updated/broadcast

Tags: windows, networking, static-ip

A static IP was changed on one on the computers on my network (Windows web server 2008 r2). Now I can't connect to that PC using its computer name. using the new IP is OK but when I ping the PC by name it uses the old static IP - How can I flush this from my system so that the computer name will work again?

We have a DC running win 2008 server r2 as our DNS server, however, it must be something cached on my machine as every other machine on the network resolves it fine.

Comment: You don't even specify you system, are you on BS2000, Linux or Windows or ...? Give more details please!

Comment: How is your network setup to resolve names? DNS? HOSTS files? NetBIOS?

Comment: That might help... Have updated with more details.

Comment: You still haven't specified the OS on your client machine. If using Windows, have you tried the following from an elevated command prompt? `ipconfig /flushdns` Also, have you double-checked for any mappings in your hosts file?

Comment: Double checked the hosts file and the issue was there after all. Thanks for giving my brain a kick.

Comment: If you have found an answer please consider posting an answer using the box below and marking it as accepted. That way if future users come along they might be able to resolve the problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

The IP address was mapped in the hosts file. Here is how to check/change the file:

http://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-7/windows-7-hosts-file/

Answer (score 0):

The below troubleshooting steps will generally work to isolate and resolve common client-side DNS lookup problems.

First, try flushing your DNS cache and try again. The Windows command for this is:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

(Must be run from an *elevated* command prompt.)

If that doesn't work, try checking the DNS name directly with `nslookup`. The Windows syntax for this is:

```
nslookup hostname
```

(Replace `hostname` with the name you want to look up.)

If `nslookup` returns the wrong IP address, there may be a problem with your DNS provider. Try checking with a different public DNS server (e.g.: Google, at 8.8.8.8).

```
nslookup hostname 8.8.8.8
```

(Will not work for LAN-based hosts.)

If this returns the correct IP, you will need to contact your DNS provider (usually, your ISP) for further support.

If the first `nslookup` returned the correct IP address, and flushing the cache didn't work, there's probably something in your local system's configuration that's preventing you from using your DNS provider to look up that system. Usually, this is caused by an entry in your hosts file. For Windows, the hosts file is located at `%WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` (no file extension). To check the hosts file, you can use `type` to output the file's contents and then re-direct it through `find` to see if any lines include the hostname you're trying to look up.

```
type %WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts | find hostname
```

If you find that there is an entry for the system in your hosts file, you'll need to either remove that line from the file or re-write it to point to the correct IP. You must do this from an *elevated* Notepad session - anyone can read the hosts file, but writing requires Admin access.